# The Error will be occured in adempiere while opening RUN_Adempiere.bat file

Tags: adempiere

1. By opening the RUN_Adempiere.bat file the following errors will be occured
2. by opening the RUN_Server2.bat just opened and move on to the invisible mode

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: all
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: all
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
   ```

   Could not find the main class: all.  Program will exit.

Comment: Please ensure that you Run the setup.bat. The problem will be solved by then.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on RUN_Server2.bat and run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Run  the `Setup.BAT` file first in the source folder and install the **`Adempiere`**, Once installed you will be able to solve the following error. Also set the Paths correctly , `JAVA_HOME` path and `ADEMPIERE_HOME` path.